# save a list of different Dataframes to json

Tags: python, json

I have different pandas dataframes, which I put in a list. 
I want to save this list in json (or any other format) which can be read by R.

```
import pandas as pd

def create_df_predictions(extra_periods):
    """
    make a empty df for predictions  
    params: extra_periods = how many prediction in the future the user wants
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'model': ['a'], 'name_id': ['a'] })
    for col in range(1, extra_periods+1):
        name_col = 'forecast' + str(col)
        df[name_col] = 0

    return df

df1 = create_df_predictions(9) 
df2 = create_df_predictions(12)
list_df = [df1, df2]
```

The question is how to save list_df in a readable format for R? Note that df1 and df2 are have a different amount of columns!

Comment: Do they need to be in a single json file, or would one json for each DataFrame be suitable?

Comment: @carthurs The idea is that the whole list in one single file is saved! Btw python is version 3.6 if this makes any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't know panda DataFrames in detail, so maybe this won't work. But in case it is kind of a traditional dict, you should be able to use the json module.

```
df1 = create_df_predictions(9) 
df2 = create_df_predictions(12)
list_df = [df1, df2]
```

You can write it to a file, using `json.dumps(list_df)`, which will convert your list of dicts to a valid json representation.

```
import json
with open("my_file", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(list_df))
```

Edit: as commented by DaveR dataframes are't serializiable. You can convert them to a dict and then dump the list to json.

```
import json
with open("my_file", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps([df.to_dict() for df in list_df]))
```

Alternatively pd.DataFrame and pd.Series have a `to_json()` method, maybe have a look at those as well.

Comment: if you tried my code you would get the following error using your solution: " is not JSON serializable"

Comment: @olish thanks, I get an error at the end with : "TypeError: keys must be a string" .  Also, I knew about the method  "to_json()" but that would convert every single df to a json file while I want to convert the whole list, right?

Comment: @DaveR that shouldn't happen with your sample code, as you have only strings as keys from `{ 'model': ['a'], 'name_id': ['a'] }`and  `name_col = 'forecast' + str(col)`. In case you add further keys/columns, make sure to convert them to string.

Comment: at the end I understood that this was not the right way to go about it. I ended up using csv for each dataframe as output which could be easily read in R

Answer (score 2):

To export the list of DataFrames to a single json file, you should convert the list into a DataFrame and then use the `to_json()` function as shown below:

```
df_to_export = pd.DataFrame(list_df)
json_output = df_to_export.to_json()
with open("output.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_output)
```

This will export the full dataset to a single json string and export it to a file.